# How to see last 7 days data from database table

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL table of feedback look like this

```
ID(int)    Body(text)    Time(TimeStamp)
--------------------------------------------
1         some text       2020-02-19 18:29:19
2         some text       2020-02-17 18:29:19
3         some text       2020-02-17 18:29:19
4         some text       2020-02-15 18:29:19
5         some text       2020-02-14 18:29:19
```

What i want to output like

```
 Days           Count
  ------------------------
   Monday          1
   Tuesday         2
   Wednesday       0
   Thursday        3
   Friday          1
   Saturday        2
   Sunday          0
```

How can achieve this by writing mySQL query.

NOTE: Data shown of feedback is not complete and just a random data.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
select dayname(TimeStamp), count(*)
from feedback
where TimeStamp >= curdate() - interval 7 day
group by dayname(TimeStamp);
```

Comment: it works.. thanks.. but its not returning last 7 days data. i need to filter that

Comment: i added an example of how you can achieve that.. i had figured you just looked for the dayname() function...